# Sigma algebra of a random number of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Consider a sequence $\{X_i\}$ of i.i.d. real r.v.'s, and an independent random variable $N$ valued in $\mathbb{N}$, interpreted as a random number of random variables from the sequence, that is $\{X_1,\ldots,X_N\}$. Can we define meaningfully the sigma algebra $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ (I am aware that the notation is meaningless, due to $N$ being random). Conceptually, my guess would be something like $\cap_{i=1}^\infty (\{X_1\in B_1,\ldots,X_i\in B_i, B_k\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), 1\leq k\leq i\}\cap\{N=i\})$. However intersecting with the event $\{N=i\}$ ruins the property of this being a sigma algebra. Is there even a way of defining such an object? Thanks for any suggestion.
EDIT: I wonder if interpreting $N$ as an independent stopping time, one could mimik the stopped sigma-algebra construction, that is $\{A\in\mathcal{F}, \{N = i\}\cap A\in\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_i)\}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the whole sigma-algebra of events. Here the obstacle is perhaps the non-measurability of $N$ with respect to the filtration though.

Comment: You could define a random variable whose value is a sigma-algebra. But what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I was curious if it makes sense to define such an object, since there are many situations on which the number of random variables is random itself, so I was thinking, when taking conditional probabilities and expectations, if there is a global concept of sigma algebra encompassing also the randomness of the number, for conditional probabilities and expectations. An example of when it could be useful is if, on top of being randomly many, they appear in random order. Then one may find useful conditioning on the values, but they are randomly many...

Comment: I would define it by $\sigma (\mathcal{F}_n,\{N=n\})$ for $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma (X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$. I'm not sure how much sense it does

Comment: @Masacroso Do you mean $\sigma (\mathcal{F}_n,1_{\{N=n\}})$ by that notation?

Comment: that was my first guess, but I am not sure it expresses the information meant by this setting. Perhaps it is just an ill defined concept